# Efficiently update MATLAB App Designer GUI real time from Simulink

Tags: matlab, user-interface, simulink

I have a Simulink model and a GUI made in app designer from which I control said model. So far I have been able to let the GUI and the Simulink model communicate both ways. The GUI sets parameter constant blocks in the model using `set_param` whereas the model updates the GUI through a callback using `add_exec_event_listener`. **The GUI object resides in the model workspace.**

In the startup callback of the model `StartFcn` I have the following  code

```
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','on');
blk = [model '/q-log']; % Block to bind listener to
event = 'PostOutputs'; % Event to bind to (fired at every sample)
app = getVariable(get_param(bdroot,'ModelWorkspace'),'app'); % The GUI

% The GUI is passed into the event handler and updated at every timestep
listener = @(obj,event) updategui(obj,event,app); 
h = add_exec_event_listener(blk, event, listener);
```

The problem with this setup is that it is extremely slow. I'm not quite sure how to get it faster and if this is the way to go. I've looked at a lot of examples but none detail my needs.

So my question is if there is a faster or more efficient way to update the GUI fields and plots? It doesn't have to be hard real time but writing variables to workspace and importing it into the GUI afterwards not is not acceptable.

Comment: Model Listener has always been the way I've done this but I totally agree that it is far from ideal. Other modeling environments provide a much easier mechanism to link models with GUIs.

Comment: Plotting reduces speed very much, you can use Simulink model for plotting.